# I get a double root context in my url when redirected to https

Tags: spring, tomcat, redirect

I have created a HelloWorld Spring MVC application using Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite). It has one Controller and one jsp. The application displays "Hello World!" on a web page. I will not post the code for this (unless asked) as it is trivial and unimportant. I am using Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1 (comes with Spring Tool Suite).

So, I add Spring 4 security, secure the root (requiresChannel().antMatchers("/").requiresSecure();) and deploy.

I type this "http://localhost:8081/helloWorld/" into my browser and I get redirected to "http://localhost:8081/helloWorld/helloWorld/".

I have used all defaults in tc-server/tomcat. I have changed absolutely nothing.

I'm guessing Tomcat is doing this and I have to switch off Tomcat redirect as I'm using Spring to do the redirect. Anybody any ideas?

```
package com.test.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws     Exception
  {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("env"));
    if(System.getProperty("env").equals("dit"))
    {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and()
        .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
    else if(System.getProperty("env").equals("sit"))
    {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and()
      .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
    else if(System.getProperty("env").equals("uat"))
    {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and()
      .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
    else if(System.getProperty("env").equals("prd"))
    {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and()
      .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    http.authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .requiresChannel()
           .antMatchers("/").requiresSecure();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out.

The company I work for has seen fit to have a process running on 8080 on our computers. This meant I had to use a port other than 8080. I used 8083. 
So I was expecting the requiresChannel to switch from port 8083 to port 8443. HttpSecurity needs to be explicitly told the mappings from insecure port to secure. By default it maps 80 to 443 and 8080 to 8443. If you want something other than the default you have to tell HttpSecurity. See below for an example.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class PortMapperSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and().formLogin()
            .permitAll().and()
            .portMapper().http(8083).mapsTo(8443).http(80).mapsTo(443);
    }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
  {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
  }
```

}